# Hide value from datalist selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, datalist

I am using datalist to display a selection of choices. When showing these choices both tha value and text are displaying, like datalist is supposed to work. However, I need to hide the value from the list, onsly showing text.

After a lot of searching I have found out that using `data-value` is supposed to work, instead of just `value`. The problem is that I dan't get it to work. The reason I am using datalist is that I need to have it in order to get a functional searchable dropdown. If it wasn't for that I would have dropped it.

My code is as follows:

```js
var myinput = document.getElementById('example');
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
myinput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById(this.value);
    divs.forEach(div => {
      div.style.display = div.id === this.value ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>This is a datalist</legend>
    <input type="text" id="example" list="brow" />
    <datalist id="brow">
        <option value="div1">Choice 1</option>
        <option value="div2">Choice 2</option>
    </datalist>
</fieldset>

<div class="hidden" id="div1">This is div1</div>
<div class="hidden" id="div2">This is div2</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a basic `<select>` instead of a `<datalist>`, since selects will only show their text, not their value by default.

Comment: @shilly As mentioned above I have to be able to search for options. That is not possible using merely a basic `<select>`.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Unless there's some browser specific code ( eg. -webkit-some-name ) to style the pseudo elements inside the datalist, I fear this won't be possible. Similar questions to this one seem to get answered by "use library x" or "create your own with a text box to search and a basic list to select from".

Answer (score 0):

It gives priority to your value in dataList, please make sure your option value and option text remain same so that duplication can be avoided

```
<fieldset>
<legend>This is a datalist</legend>
<input type="text" id="example" list="brow" />
<datalist id="brow">
    <option value="Choice 1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="Choice 2">Choice 2</option>
</datalist>
```